# Sufficiency - Knowns and Unknowns

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics

I have a self-study question that goes as follows:

Let $X$ be one observation from a $N\sim(0, \sigma^2)$ population. Is $|X|$ a sufficient statistic?

My question is - since you KNOW the $\mu$ parameter here is $0$, should this question be read as is $|X|$ a sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$, the variance? A lot of the questions in my book (Casella) proceed this way, without identifying which parameter that the statistic is sufficient for.

Comment: Certainly for the variance - the mean is a priori zero. And, is it sufficient?

Comment: There's only one parameter in the question, so there's no much chance of ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is - since you KNOW the $\mu$ parameter here is 0, should this question be read as is $|X|$ a sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$, the variance?

Yes, that's the way it should be read. In fact, there is no $\mu$ parameter here -- the mean is just zero for all distributions in the considered family. Thus, we are dealing with a one-parameter family and it's understood it's that one parameter the question refers to.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that $\mu=0$ there is only one unknown parameter, $\sigma^2$ and the density can be written
$$
   f(x;\sigma^2) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp(-\frac12(x/\sigma)^2)
$$
Note that, since $x$ enters the density only in squared form, and since 
$x^2 = |x|^2$ we have that
$f(x;\sigma^2) = f(|x|;\sigma^2)$
so the likelihood function is the same, in terms of $x$ and in terms of $|x|$. 
Then you should be able to conclude, for instance using the factorization theorem.

(And yes, $|x|$ is a sufficient statistic here).